# android apk run and shutdown suddenly

Tags: android, react-native

I use react-native to build and install apk on Nexus 5X, but suddenly shutdown. I use adb logcat to find this errors:

```
01-06 10:04:19.086 12909 12926 I ReactNativeJS: Running application "YCParAppAndroid" with appParams: {"initialProps":{},"rootTag":1}. __DEV__ === false, development-level warning are OFF, performance optimizations are ON
01-06 10:04:19.343 12909 12926 E ReactNativeJS: null is not an object (evaluating 'e.username')
01-06 10:04:19.379 12909 12927 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
01-06 10:04:19.379 12909 12927 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.ycparappandroid, PID: 12909
01-06 10:04:19.379 12909 12927 E AndroidRuntime: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: null is not an object (evaluating 'e.username'), stack:
01-06 10:04:19.379 12909 12927 E AndroidRuntime: value@590:2102
01-06 10:04:19.379 12909 12927 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@65:562
01-06 10:04:19.379 12909 12927 E AndroidRuntime: callTimer@60:785
01-06 10:04:19.379 12909 12927 E AndroidRuntime: callTimers@60:1203
01-06 10:04:19.379 12909 12927 E AndroidRuntime: value@58:2827
01-06 10:04:19.379 12909 12927 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@58:1062
01-06 10:04:19.379 12909 12927 E AndroidRuntime: d@58:130
01-06 10:04:19.379 12909 12927 E AndroidRuntime: value@58:1034
01-06 10:04:19.379 12909 12927 E AndroidRuntime:
01-06 10:04:19.379 12909 12927 E AndroidRuntime: at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.showOrThrowError(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:97)
01-06 10:04:19.379 12909 12927 E AndroidRuntime: at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportFatalException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:81)
01-06 10:04:19.379 12909 12927 E AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-06 10:04:19.379 12909 12927 E AndroidRuntime: at com.facebook.react.bridge.BaseJavaModule$JavaMethod.invoke(BaseJavaModule.java:318)
01-06 10:04:19.379 12909 12927 E AndroidRuntime: at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:158)
01-06 10:04:19.379 12909 12927 E AndroidRuntime: at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
01-06 10:04:19.379 12909 12927 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
01-06 10:04:19.379 12909 12927 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-06 10:04:19.379 12909 12927 E AndroidRuntime: at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
01-06 10:04:19.379 12909 12927 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
01-06 10:04:19.379 12909 12927 E AndroidRuntime: at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196)
01-06 10:04:19.379 12909 12927 E AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Did any one meet this problem?

Comment: e.username is null . You could debug and check why it is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a null error, my friend:

```
null is not an object (evaluating 'e.username')
```

Comment: Thank you! I focus on the FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules error but forgot to see the null error. I should add null assessment in my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- Check if your native module is returning a valid Promise or resolving
  a Callback.
- Make sure your return value is of [Type](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/bridge/ReadableType.java)
- Make sure your native module js file is returning valid Promise or Callbacl

`01-06 10:04:19.343 12909 12926 E ReactNativeJS: null is not an object (evaluating 'e.username')`

You are trying to reference property of null object, that's the error

Comment: Thank you,problem solved ! I focus on the FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules error but forgot to see the null error. I should add null assessment in my code. Thanks!